# Tabular row height of header with vertical allignment

Tags: tables

How to set the row height of a single row (the header in this case) with vertically center alignment?

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
        \begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} | *4{p{0.22\linewidth} | } }
            \hline
            \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\small \textbf{Alfa}} &
            \multicolumn{1}{ c|}{\small \textbf{Bravo}}   &
            \multicolumn{1}{ c|}{\small \textbf{Charlie}}  &
            \multicolumn{1}{ c|}{\small \textbf{Delta}} \\ \hline \hline
            Name: \vspace{0.8cm} & Name: & Name: & Name: \\  
            \hline
            Date: \vspace{0.8cm}& Date: & Date: & Date: \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with the `makecell` package, which defines a common formatting for cells introduced by the `\thead`, `\makecell` and a few other commands. Among the parameters are lengths added at the top and bottom of these cells, through the `\Gape` command.

I also suggest to use the `tabularx` environment. Below, I give four possibilities:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

 \usepackage{tabularx, makecell, booktabs}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{\Gape[3ex]}
\renewcommand\cellgape{\Gape[4pt][0.8cm]}

 \begin{document}

 \centering
        \begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} | *4{p{0.22\linewidth} | } }
            \hline
            \thead{Alfa} &
            \thead{Bravo} &
            \thead{Charlie} &
            \thead{Delta} \\ \hline \hline
            Name: \vspace{0.8cm} & Name: & Name: & Name: \\
            \hline
            Date: \vspace{0.8cm}& Date: & Date: & Date: \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
\vskip 1cm
 \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|*4{X |}}
            \hline
            \thead{Alfa} &
            \thead{Bravo} &
            \thead{Charlie} &
            \thead{Delta} \\ \hline \hline
            Name: \vspace{0.8cm} & Name: & Name: & Name: \\
            \hline
            Date: \vspace{0.8cm}& Date: & Date: & Date: \\ \hline
        \end{tabularx}
\vskip 1cm
 \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l*4{X }}
             & \thead{Alfa} &
            \thead{Bravo} &
            \thead{Charlie} &
            \thead{Delta} \\
            \toprule
            Name: \vspace{0.8cm} & & & & \\
            \cmidrule(l){1-5}
            Date: \vspace{0.8cm}& & & & \\
           \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
\vskip 1cm
 \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l!{\vrule width1pt}*4{X }}
             & \thead{Alfa} &
            \thead{Bravo} &
            \thead{Charlie} &
            \thead{Delta} \\
            \Xhline{1pt}
            \makecell[tl]{Name: } & & & & \\
            \makecell[tl]{Date:} & & & & \\
        \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]